# I am trying to make an API request based on the result of another API request using forEach. How I could archive the same result without using forEach

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, react-hooks

I am trying to make an API request based on the result of another API request. I got it working the way I want it but I don't like to use forEach for my API call and I can't wrap my head around how to get in done with a different method. Are there any suggestions on how I could do it in a more efficient way, eg. with promise.all?

here is my code:

**api.js**

```
export const fetchOrders = () => {
  return fetch(`${url}/work_orders`).then(res => res.json());
};

export const fetchWorker = id => {
  return fetch(`${url}/workers/${id}`).then(res => res.json());
};
```

**app.js**

```
function OrderReducer(state, action) {
  if (action.type === "fetch") {
    return {
      orders: [],
      error: null,
      loading: true
    };
  } else if (action.type === "success") {
    return {
      ...state,
      orders: [
        ...state.orders,
        {
          order: action.order,
          worker: action.worker
        }
      ],
      loading: false
    };
  } else if (action.type === "error") {
    return {
      ...state,
      error: action.message,
      loading: false
    };
  } else {
    throw new Error("no action type initialized");
  }
}

const Orders = () => {
  const [state, dispatch] = React.useReducer(OrderReducer, {
    orders: [],
    error: null,
    loading: true
  });

  React.useEffect(() => {
    dispatch({ type: "fetch" });

    fetchOrders()
      .then(({ orders }) => {
        return orders;
      })
      .then(orders =>
        orders.forEach(order => {
          fetchWorker(order.workerId).then(({ worker }) =>
            dispatch({ type: "success", order, worker })
          );
        })
      )
      .catch(({ message }) => dispatch({ type: "error", message }));
  }, []);
```

**archived output:**

```
orders:[
 0: {
  order:{...},
  worker:{...}
},
 ...
 ...
 ...
 20: {
  order:{...},
  worker:{...}
}
]
```

Comment: you can get workers detail from api side in `fetchOrders` api for each order by tweaking your api logic, if api are made by you.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the following fetch

```
const fetchWorker = async order => {
  const res = await fetch(`${url}/workers/${order.workerId}`);
  const { worker } = await res.json();
  return { order, worker };
};

const fetchOrders = async () => {
  const res = await fetch(`${url}/work_orders`);
  const { orders } = await res.json();
  return Promise.all(orders.map(order => fetchWorker(order)));
};

fetchOrders()
  .then(data => console.log(data))
  .catch(({ message }) => console.log(message));
```

and it retuned what I was trying to get.
an array, each object with a value of order and worker

```
[20]
[ { order:...., worker:... }, ...]
```

any suggestions on how to improve the code?